# Python script using PIL works in IDE doesn't when run by cmd and gives 'PIL' has no attribute 'Image'

Tags: python, cmd

When I run the following in the Spyder IDE on Win10:

```
import PIL
import os

Inboundfile = "C:/Test/test/Overlay.png"

image = PIL.Image.open(os.path.abspath(Inboundfile))
image.show()
```

It works fine. Opens the picture and outputs:

```
runfile('C:/Users/bob/Anaconda3/envs/NewEnvironment/bob/test3.py', wdir='C:/Users/bob/Anaconda3/envs/NewEnvironment/bob')
```

But when I call the same script from a cmd prompt:

```
C:\Users\bob\Anaconda3\envs\NewEnvironment\bob>python test3.py
```

It results in:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test3.py", line 14, in <module>
    image = PIL.Image.open(os.path.abspath(Inboundfile))
AttributeError: module 'PIL' has no attribute 'Image'
```

I have verified that the environment path is pointing to the same python environment as the IDE.  ( I think )  Here is my Path variable from OS

```
C:\Users\bob\Anaconda3\envs\NewEnvironment\
```

It's probably something very simple but I'm very new at this and any help would be appreciated.

I tried adding the line:

```
from PIL import Image
```

It still runs fine in the IDE but the error message changes to:

```
C:\Users\bb\Anaconda3\envs\NewEnvironment\bob>python test3.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test3.py", line 11, in <module>
    from PIL import Image
  File "C:\Users\bob\Anaconda3\envs\NewEnvironment\lib\site-packages\PIL\Image.py", line 69, in <module>
    from . import _imaging as core
ImportError: DLL load failed: The specified module could not be found.
```

This is even more confusing as I can follow that path and see Image.py sitting in the directory. What is the IDE doing that CMD is not?

Comment: It's almost certainly a difference in the `PYTHONPATH` between the two environments.

Comment: Failure to load a DLL in one environment but not another is almost always a bitness problem. This is because a Windows executable cannot load a DLL of a different bitness, and may even claim that it isn't there, when you can see that it is. I suspect that your Anaconda environment is running 64-bit Python and your command line environment is running 32-bit, or vice versa.  This is quick to check. Do `sys.version` in both environments.

Comment: Tried creating a brand new environment.  Tried bypassing path variable by directly calling the python.exe in the new environment.  If I have the same script print out all the items in sys.path, I see one extra path when it runs in the IDE ( Ipython\extenstions).  If I have it print all the sys.modules.keyes() I see that the ID has a TON of extra things.  Most noteworthy if run in the IDE it has PIL.Image and others, but if run using cmd it only has PIL and PIL._version.  Also of note:  If I try to import numpy it works fine in the IDE but breaks when run in cmd : "... c-extensions failed".

Answer (score 0):

All of my problems vanished when I simply closed and restarted the console I was using to call the python script.  I have learned that the console saves things like the path variables when it starts up and must be restarted to get changes.